# range loop using lvalue reference and assignment operator deletion

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate using reference. I have a C++ class with assignment operator overload deleted.

For the following code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
 class Data
 {
     public:
     Data(){};
     
     void operator=(Data &) = delete;;
     
     void operator=(Data &&) = delete;
 };
int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> vec = {Data(), Data(), Data()};
    
    for (const auto &it : vec)
    {
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is there something I can do to keep the loop without using assignment operator overload?
Other than using raw pointers of course

As I understand, lvalue reference creation doesn't call constructor or assignment operator overload.

```
Data foo; // default constructor
Data& data = foo; // no constructor or assigment operator is called
```

Comment: In the future, please include the compiler errors verbatim in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is the vector, not the loop.

This compiles and runs fine.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
class Data {
  public:
    Data() {};
    void operator=(Data &) = delete;;
    void operator=(Data &&) = delete;
};

int main() {
  std::array<Data, 3> vec;
  // std::vector<Data> vec = {Data(), Data(), Data()};
    
  for (const auto &it : vec) {}
  return 0;
}
```

Vectors require a copy (or move) constructor to exist, because when adding elements, it may resize the vector, which may require moving the elements to a new chunk of memory.

Comment: They can add `Data(const Data&) = default;` to get the initializer list to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/920bba696d04ae80